# I am trying to display the photo from Azure AD on my accounts page in python

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get the profile image from Azure AD and want to display that image in a div. My server code is following, although I am not sure how can I display that image in the div.

```
def account():
token = _get_token_from_cache(app_config.SCOPE)
if not token:
    return redirect(url_for("login"))
graph_data = requests.get(  # Use token to call downstream service
    app_config.ACCOUNT_INFO,
    headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token['access_token']},
    ).json()
#endpoint = '/users/firstname.lastname@somecompany.com/photo/$value'
photo_responce = requests.get(app_config.PHOTO_ENDPOINT, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token['access_token']},stream=True)
photo_status_code = photo_responce.ok
if photo_status_code:
    photo = photo_responce.raw.read()
else:
    photo = ''
```

From this code, I am getting the raw data of the photo, which looks like below.

```
b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00`\x00`\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\xff\xdb\x00C\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\xff\xc0\x00\x11\x08\x02\x88\x02\x88\x03\x01"\x00\x02\x11\x01\x03\x11\x01\xff\xc4\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x01\x05\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\xff\xc4\x00\xb5\x10\x00\x02\x01\x03\x03\x02\x04\x03\x05\x05\x04\x04\x00\x00\x01}\x01\x02\x03\x00\x04\x11\x05\x12!1A\x06\x13Qa\x07"q\x142\x81\x91\xa1\x08#B\xb1\xc1\x15R\xd1\xf0$3br\x82\t\n\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a%&\'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xff\xc4\x00\x1f\x01\x00\x03\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\xff\xc4\x00\xb5\x11\x00\x02\x01\x02\x04\x04\x03\x04\x07\x05\x04\x04\x00\x01\x02w\x00\x01\x02\x03\x11\x04\x05!1\x06\x12AQ\x07aq\x13"2\x81\x08\x14B\x91\xa1\xb1\xc1\t#3R\xf0\x15br\xd1\n\x16$4\xe1%\xf1\x17\x18\x19\x1a&\'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xff\xda\x00\x0c\x03\x01\x00\x02\x11\x03\x11\x00?\x00\xfe_\xff\x00j"\xdf\xf0\xd3?\xb4A\xc8\xe3\xe3\x97\xc5p7g\x1f\xf2>\xeb\xeap0\x0f\x03\x92FFq\x9c\xd7\x89\xa4d\x00\xe3\x8c\x91\xd3\x03\x19*7c#*:6\x08\x19\x1f(,\r{g\xedE\xbb\xfe\x1ao\xf6\x86\xc0\xc9\xff\x00\x85\xe5\xf1g\xdcm\xff\x00\x84\xef^8\xc9\x18\xdd\xd7\x03\x9e\xf8\xe75\xe2j\x19Y[\x9c\x03\xdc\xe4\xe7o*y$\xb0\xc9\xce9\x04\xfa\xd0\x05\xb8\xf1\x80\x06O\xde\xe0\x90\xa0\xf7\xea}\x18g\x90}[\x9c\x1ak\x1c.B\x96n\xe3?*\x9cg\x8e8\xe4\x93\xc6:pO`&Op\xa5r\xc3\x05B\x92N\xdd\xb8\xc9\xe7\x01\x88\xe7<\x06$u~\xd6\x1d\x83`\x1c\xe099Q\x80N\x14\xfa\x9e;\x9c\xe3\x00P\x03q\x8c(nyl\x1c\xf4\xe4\x82y\x00m\xea8\x01\xba\x1ey\xa5#\x04ps\x83\xeczm|\x83\x81\xdf\x18\xe7\x9c\x03\xc6A\x9ff\xe1\xbb\xe5\x07r\xf2v\x903\x8c\x92\x06p\x0f]\xdb\xb2\x07P\x0eE8.I\xef\x91\xcb\x0c0\x18\x19\xc8\x04p>\xebm\x07\xef`\xf0\x05\x00WP\xcd\x8e\x18\x12s\xd4\x9c\xe3i\x0c\xcd\x9c\x96\xc6\xd2\xb9$\x06\xe0\x1e3W\xa1\xda\xa4\xe7<p\x0e>_\xee\x8c\x92\x0eT\xf2\x1b\xa7\xa9\xe9\x93\x1f\x94\t\xe8\xc7%J\x8c\x12\xc0\x01\xce\xc2\x08\xe3p?.G\xcb\x9e98\xb3\n`m\xc1#\x1dy\xc0\x04\x11\xeb\x8eO\x04\xf3\x81\x9e8\x14\x01e@\x19\xe0\x1d\xa3\x8e\xd9\x1c\x0cd\x9e\xb9\xc6=@\xdd\x9eja\x903\xf7A#\xa7\x00\x1cg\x04u\xe9\x8c\x1c\xed\xe0\x81H\xa0\x85\\\xa8\xc8\x00\x81\x90A\xc6@\x038\xdd\xf2\x91\x8c\xf3\x8f\x97\x18 T\x87*2N0\xa0\x16\xc7Bq\x80\x0e>P\xcb\x9e\x98 \x93\xcf\x02\x80"8\xc7\xca6\x8epI\xe3<\x13\x8ct\xe0\x86<c9\xfb\xf9 W\xc8\xe7\x19\x00\x00@\x18\xe0\xf3\x86\x07\x93\xdf\x85\xc0;z\xf2\x0e,\x11\x91\x91\xce\xe0Alg\x91\xdc\xa9\xc6>PA\'\x90[\xa1\x07%\x84\x16\xe7\x1bHl\x9e\xbd\x062Fx\xc0\xea\x06y\xc9\xeesI\xdfM:\xeb\xe8\x05v\xc8\x1d9\r\xcb\x02\xaa\xdd\xba\x9e\x06s\xd3\x8e\xa4\x13\xda\x98\xaayV\xc19<\xff\x00\x1f<\x0cq\xb9\xbeb8\xfb\xa7\xa9\x1c`\xcc3\xb4mP~V \x03\xf2\xe0\xf3\x9c\x86\x1f9=\x01\x18;\xb0\x1b\x03\x00\n\xd9\xc9;s\xfc \xf5\x04.@# r\t\x04\x8f\x98\x9c`\x01L\x06`\x0c\xb7Bwt\x0c\xc7\x00`g8\xe4\x82?\x8bv;\x80\x06#\x99\x00F\xca\xe3\xe6\xe009\xc7\\\x10s\x91\x9e\x06>`{|\xb9\xab\x1fw\x1bp\xdbB\xed\x04\x15\xc1\xeb\xb8\x828$\x93\xbb9\xe9\xcf\x0b\xc42\x06\\\xe7-\xb87\x07\x81\xbb\xf8H\xceq\xcfL\x83\xdcg\x90(\x03\x02\xe7\'\xd7\x04\xf1\x93\xdbv\x18\x11\xcf^F\x07c\x9c\xfaQe=N\xdf\x98\x90H=A\xc8Q\x82\x0eq\xc9\xcf\xf7\x81\xc1 \x83W\xa7\xdd\xe6\xb7\x079\x19 \x1c\r\xc3 \x108\xc7A\xf2\x82Fq\x9e\xb9\xa7\xf3\x1c\xe3$\xe0\xe7\x1fx\xf3\xc2\x83\x9cc\xb3\x1c\x83\xe9\x9eh\x01\xa8\x98\x18\xdd\x80O|\x83\x83\xc8\'\x93\x96C\xd0\xfarE]L7L\xed\x03?1#8\xecH\xce9\x01pG\x00\x8c\xa8\xc9\xa8\x141\xdc\xa4\xe0d)\xce\x18\xe4\x8e\xbc}\xe1\xc1\xe0\xf2F;dU\xa5\xc9
```

I am not sure how to convert this data so that I can get the image. This is not binary data.
Please help

Thanks

Comment: Its a JPEG image data, Please look into [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39178896/python-convert-bytes-literal-to-image) and use the image.

Comment: Moving this to Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data which you are seeing is a JPEG Image format data. Please look into the code provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39178896/python-convert-bytes-literal-to-image) and then use that image to show up in the div tag.